# Unable to post array-data to using node js, angular, and mongoDb

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am posting form-data.

Front-end is in angular Js.
Iam able to post data from front-end,because i logged on angular console, and it's showing all data.
But when did console.log on node js server, then I am getting array fields as **[object object]**
Non-array fields i.e **Objects** are coming correct.

**Model :**

```
var productsSchema = new Schema({
   productName: {type: String, required: false},
    productDescription: {type: String, required: false},
 productStock: [
    {
        size: {type: Number, required: false},
        price: {type: Number, required: false},
        imagePaths: [{
            image1:{type: String, required: false},
            image2:{type: String, required: false},
            image3:{type: String, required: false},
            image4:{type: String, required: false}
        }]
    }
    ])}
```

**Angular Code**

```
$scope.product = {};
    $scope.newProduct = function(){
      var formData = new FormData;
      for(key in $scope.product){
        formData.append(key, $scope.product[key]);
      } 
  //getting the files
  var file = $('#file')[0].files[0];
  formData.append('image', file);
  //formData.append('product',$scope.product);
  //Post data
  $http.post('http://localhost:3000/products/api/new-product',formData,{
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
  }).then(function(res){
    $scope.item = res.data;
  });
  console.log($scope.product);
  //console.log(file.name);
}
```

Why this happening, what I am doing wrong? 
Please help.

Comment: Are you using JSON.stringify() on the data before posting, and JSON.parse() after? If not, how are you posting the data, and how are you parsing it server side?

Comment: not, I am not using JSON.stringify() before posting data. I am simple posting  `$scope.product` to my API

Comment: I have updated my angular code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In NodeJS, console.log and console.dir would only go 2 levels deep when displaying your object (you see [Object] instead of actual contents of nested objects). If you wanna see full object either you can stringify or use util.inspect function

Comment: I used `console.log(util.inspect(req.body));`, still got `productStock` as **[object object]**

Comment: try this util.inspect(req.body, {depth: null})

Comment: for more info : https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options

Comment: did `console.log(util.inspect(req.body, {depth: null}));`, still  got `productStock` as **[object object]**

Comment: console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body)); ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151832/discussion-between-mayank-bisht-and-korcan).